# Read registers on a NIC card on Windows

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, network-adapter, debug

I have a Realtek Ethernet Controller on my x86 machine running Windows 7. I have the datasheet for the Ethernet controller. I am trying to debug a low-level issue and I need to read certain registers from the NIC. Is there a tool/utility on Windows that allows me to read the registers?

Update: With RW-Everything I can see the PCI config space registers of the devices attached to the system. However, I would like to access the PHY registers mentioned in the NIC's datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Check out R/W Everything (http://rweverything.com/).  I've used it many times for just such a situation.

Comment: I did try that but it only shows the PCI configuration space registers for the NIC card on my Windows. How can I read the rest of the registers that are in the datasheet? Do I have to specify any specific indexing address sequence to access those registers?